# AlphaComposite - alpha value converges

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage, alpha, composite

I'm having problems with something that should be quite simple. I'm painting 1% opaque boxes on top of one another. After 100 paints I would expect the opacity to reach 100%, however the opacity (alpha value) converges below 100% and stops increasing. To demonstrate this problem I have simplified my code to this:

```
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();

    float alpha = 0.01f;
    Color c = new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha);
    g2.setColor(c);

    while (true) {
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        System.out.println(new Color(bi.getRGB(5, 5), true).getAlpha() / 255f);
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
```

It draws filled white boxes with an alpha of 0.01 (1% opacity) over one another then tests what the alpha at the centre of the drawing area is. I thought this should increase like so: 0%, 1%, 2%, 3% ... 100%. However, instead it slowly converges to 83.5% and stops increasing oddly. I'm think this is to do with the AlphaComposite but have tried endlessly to find a way of making a simple linear alphaNEW = alphaDST + alphaSRC operation without success. An alpha of 0.5 or above does reach 1.0 at the centre however - although not linearly as I would like. All the composites seem to use the format 'alpha' and/or '1 - alpha' for source and destination pixels... Any ideas?

Cheers :)

EDIT: What I'm trying to achieve is something linear (1%, 2%, 3% opacity...) and not dissimilar to how Photoshop would operate if you painted the same area over and over with 1% opaque paint it eventually reaches 100% opaque, it doesn't stop at 80%!

Comment: Have you tried setting the [`RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION) to `VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY` (using `g2.setRenderingHint(...)`? Could be rounding errors. Not sure if it has an effect, but worth exploring.

Answer (score 1):

Alpha composting is not 'additive' by default. Normally the final alpha is calculated as an 'in' operator. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) has more information on this. However, if you want additive composting you may have to implement your own [custom composting function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Composite.html).